# How to convert a Scala Array to ArrayBuffer?

Tags: scala

I see that a Scala Array can be easily converted to List, Seq etc, using the s.toList or s.toSeq. Now, I would like to convert an array to a bufferarray. How would I do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `Iterable: _*`:

```
val arr = Array(1,2,3)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

val buf = collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(arr: _*)
buf: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
```

The `_*` means to `unpack` the `Iterable` elements. So `arr: _*` unpacks the elements of `arr` into a variable length list - which is an acceptable parameter list for `ArrayBuffer.

Comment: Could you please explain the "_*" part?

Comment: Represents the elements of the `Iterable` .  The underscore represents an individual element and the asterisk signifies: "now take _all_ of them"

Answer (score 21):

There's a generic method `to` that can convert between arbitrary collection types.

```
Array(1, 2, 3).to[ArrayBuffer]
```

Or from Scala 2.13 onwards:

```
Array(1, 2, 3).to(ArrayBuffer)
```

Answer (score 4):

please try `Array(1, 2, 3).toBuffer`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is now looking for the answer, the answer which has been accepted is deprecated. If you will try to execute it then it will execute it successfully but will give you a warning message. So either you can refer Claire Hou answer or you can use

```
Array('a','b','c').toIndexedSequence
```